# how to add data to picker view when i enter text in the textbox and clicks the button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

```
pickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"abc",@"zxc",@"xyz",@"qwe", nil];
```

That is my array populating `pickerview` and I have a textfield and button.
When user enters some text and taps button, `pickerview` should update with the new text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
[pickerArray addObject:new_text];
[pickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your object into pickerArray and call reloadAllComponents method from your picker. As documentation says:

> Reloads all components of the picker view. Calling this method causes
>   the picker view to query the delegate for new data for all components.

Answer (score 0):

Add Components in `pickerview array` and `reloadAllComponents`

**Objective-C**

```
[pickerview reloadAllComponents];
```

**Swift**

```
pickerview.reloadAllComponents()
```

[UIPickerView/reloadAllComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/reloadAllComponents)